How can I upload more details in listings feed as personal account on facebook?
When uploading a feed with multiple products there is no column in the template for SKU or image. Which means I have to manually sit and edit these things one by one since I have a lot of listings for sale it would take me for ever.
I noticed as a merchant you can upload a different feed with these information.
Is there no way to upload a feed with this content as a personal account so I don't have to manually edit one by one for listing to become live?
Thank you so much!
